# Android API 26 and above Media player Issue

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-8.0-oreo

I use this code to run a .wav sound file with media player
It works fine with all android versions except Android O ( API 26 ) it has a random behavior like ( play for the first 1 or 2 seconds ) or play the complete sound.
I don't know whats is going on with Android O, I was having an issue with localization but I solve it too, also was working fine for all other versions except API 26.

this is my code

```
 fun playSplashScreenMp3(context: Context){

            val welcomeMp3 = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound)

            welcomeMp3.start()  

    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by declaring the Mediaplayer globally on the top of the class.